# > library(bibliometrix) Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’: object ‘if_all’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'

Tags: jquery

While uploading bibliometrix library i am getting the following errors,

> library(bibliometrix)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’:
> object ‘if_all’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'

Answer (score 1):

try install.packages("tidyverse"), it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these codes and it worked for me:

```
remove.packages("rlang")
remove.packages("dplyr")

install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("dplyr")

library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
```

Huge thanks to Vinit from https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5214